# Show that $N$ is the only subgroup of that given order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Given that $N$ is a normal subgroup of a group $G$ such that $o(N)$ and $o(G/N)$ are co prime. Show that  $N$ is the only  subgroup of that given order and that if $x^{(o(N))}=e$ then $x\in N$.

I don't know how to attack this problem. I have no idea where to start. Plz anyone help me with this

Comment: Always try to vote up an answer which has helped you so much !Haha

Comment: Thank u so much for helping me sir

Comment: Happy to help you,my friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $o(N)=m,o(G/N)=p$ then $\gcd(p,m)=1;o(G)=pm$

Let $K$ be another subgroup of $G$ of order $m$.

$NK$ is a subgroup of $G$ .Hence $o(NK)=\dfrac{o(N)o(K)}{o(N\cap K}=\dfrac{m.m}{d};d=o(N\cap K)$

So $\dfrac{m^2}{d}|pm\implies \dfrac{m}{d}|p\implies m|pd\implies m|d$

Also $d|m\implies d=m\implies N=K$